# Passing model instance variable from one controller to another in redirect_to in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails version 3.2.10. I am trying to pass a model instance variable with many attributes in it from one action to another action in different controller.

I have tried many things, but not getting a solution.

First controller method:

```
def create
if current_user
  auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  @applicant = Applicant.new
  if (auth['provider'] == "linkedin")
    puts auth.info.image
    linkedinProfileImport(auth)
    @applcant.first_name = auth.info.first_name
    @applcant.second_name = auth.info.last_name

   redirect_to controller => 'job_applicants', :action => 'newProfile' , :id => params[:id]
    end
```

Second controller method:

```
 def newProfile
 @job = Job.find_by_id(params[:id])
 puts @job.id
 @applicant = Applicant.new
 @applicant = @applicant
```

end

I have to access the `@ applicant` variable from first controller into second controller method.

Comment: Either `@applcant` is a typo here, or was the root cause of a problem in your actual code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just can't do that... You will have to store your object in DB in the first action and then retrieve it in the second one.

With a redirect_to, you can pass arguments as you would in a url for example, not complete objects. Here you would pass the saved object id in the redirect_to.

Comment: but i am not saving it in the database. i have used omniauth to have authentication and gathering details, that i store in @applicant, which i have to use in different controller showing a form with pre-filled values from it. so i have to access that vales there without saving them. please give me the other way out.

Answer (score 0):

You should move a lot of this logic from the controller into the model.

So, I would have a model method:

```
def create #in the controller
  if current_user
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    @applicant = Applicant.create_from_omniauth_hash(auth)

   redirect_to controller => 'job_applicants', :action => 'newProfile' , :id => params[:id]
end  



class Applicant < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.create_from_omniauth_hash(auth)
    applicant = Applicant.new
    if (auth['provider'] == "linkedin")
      puts auth.info.image
      linkedinProfileImport(auth)
      applicant.first_name = auth.info.first_name
      applicant.second_name = auth.info.last_name
    end
    create_new_profile(applicant)
    applicant.save!
  end

  def create_new_profile(applicant)
    applicant.job = "job"
  end
end
```

Comment: but by doing this, how can access the variable?

Comment: you call this method from the `create` method in the controller, and then you redirect to the page you need. I'll edit the question a bit to show you how it would work.